# Download file from firebase storage with HTTP request that anyone can download

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xmlhttprequest, firebase-storage

I am attempting to download a file from a firebase storage bucket using a HTTP request.

```js
bucket.file('<filepath>').getSignedUrl({
   action: 'read',
   expires: '03-17-2025'
})
.then((url: any) => {
   console.log(url);
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.responseType = 'blob';
   xhr.onload = (event) => {
      xhr.response;
   };
   xhr.open('GET', url);
   xhr.send();
})
.catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
});
```

However when I do this I get "Error: The caller does not have permission".

How do I make it so that anyone can download it with a link? I can worry about permissions and security later, this is just for testing.

---

Security Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /<folder>/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true; //allow anyone with link to read from the folder
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null; //all other locations are secured by auth
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` - so I believe I need to make it so that for only this folder within the bucket anyone can read no matter the auth, but keep the rules strict for any other storage location. I'll give the syntax a try, but I dont know it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message (`"Error: The caller does not have permission"`) and the above comments (i.e. currently, your Storage security rules are `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`), it appears that your security rules prevent the user to generate the signed URL with the `getSignedUrl()`method:

So you should:

- Either sign-in the user in such a way `request.auth` is not `null`.
- Or adapt the Security Rules in order to allow unauthenticated users to read Objects in the bucket. Of course, this means that everybody can download these Objects, so it should probably be done only in a test environment.
- Or implement any other adaptation that grants the user the read access to the desired Object.

---

Note: Using `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null` in your Firestore or Cloud Storage security rules **is usually not sufficient**. As a matter of fact it is not difficult to get your Firebase config values from your app, therefore someone can easily use the Auth REST API to create an account in your Firebase project.

Comment: I will attempt to only allow read, but not write in 1 folder within the bucket. This way everywhere else would be secure.

Comment: I have added the security rule for the bucket in question, but it still throws the same error. Can you see anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: You need to write `allow read: if true;`

Comment: It's strange that it says it has access in the `Rules playground` when it clearly doesn't. Odd. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Try to put a rule only for one specific bucket, just to test if this simple case works.

Comment: On top of the `allow read: if true;` solution I needed to add `Service Account Token Creator` and `Storage Object Creator` roles to my default service account in IAM settings, then it worked perfectly.